# Make a field read only based on value in ASP.net: C#, ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, code-behind

Everyone that has responded to my questions have been so very helpful and I am closing in on finishing this app. My challenge now is to make 3 fields read only based on a login.

I have the following code that does exactly what I need and assign the currently logged in user to a text field. What I want to do is make some other text fields (Read Only) if the login user does not equal a specific value. For example, if submitted_by_email_username does not equal administrator1@samplecompany.com then make the text field (Salary_in) which is a textbox, Read Only. I can read code much than I write it these days so I apologize if this is a simple request. I would like to make three fields Read Only based on that logic in the COde Behind.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (submitted_by_email_username != null)
    {
        _ = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            submitted_by_email_username.Text = User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need code in `Page_PreInit` 99.9% of the time in webforms. Even with dynamic controls you would only need `Page_Load`.

But you can make a TextBox readonly by using the `Enabled` property.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        submitted_by_email_username.Enabled = false;
        submitted_by_email_username.Text = User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```